# Anchor Name Not Connecting to Anchor Link

Tags: hyperlink, tags, anchor, internal

I have a menu button on a mobile site I am building and it is linked to my navigation menu at the bottom so the user can click it and drop straight down to the menu. I have checked over the HTML many times but I am not sure why it isn't working on this particular site.  (The site [can be found here](http://www.absolutenexus.net/tiffin-music-and-art-festival/mobile).)

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#bottom_nav">Menu</a>
```

Linked to:

```
<a href="" name="bottom_nav" id="bottom_nav"><img src=""/></a>
```

I have tried linking it to a name attribute and also to an id. Neither have worked. Does anyone see an issue with my code?  I have even tried adding the name and id to the img tag also.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be trying to load too many versions of jQuery at one time... which somehow seems to be preventing your link anchor to jump to your named anchor.

*At the top of your web page you have this:*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

*Then, at the bottom of your web page you have this:*

```
<script src="/tiffin-music-and-art-festival/mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/tiffin-music-and-art-festival/mobile/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
<script src="/tiffin-music-and-art-festival/mobile/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Try and decide which jQuery version you really want to include, and then remove the extra lines.  Then... the link jump should work.

Comment: @user1513829 Glad to hear it!  And if you have the chance, it'd be great if you could accept this answer so that the question becomes "resolved " :)  Thanks!

Comment: It wont let me because I don't have enough points. I'll log in with my normal account and upvote it!

Comment: @user1513829 Oh, haha; no worries;